# op amp - what's the connection between output and input through a resistor for?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpdocq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi, 
    Vi is a sinusodial signal with a DC 1.65V offset. In my analysis, the gain for the sinusodial signal is 1+R2/R3. Then what is the R4 connection for?

Comment: To make the analysis more difficult...

Comment: Simulate it in say LTSpice and run it with and without R4. Live and learn?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the input impedance.

With the proper choice of resistor values, something special can be achieved.